# I cant find out the error in unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dataviewmanager

---

```
recyclerView =findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.demo_recyclerview).apply {

            setHasFixedSize(true)


            layoutManager = viewManager


            adapter = demoAdapter

        }
```

[Error in a recycler view(Unresolved reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW34G.png)

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. No one-liner.

Comment: Include all of your issues in the question, no external links.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate view first. Something like

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.fragment_contacts, null)
```

then you can find your recycler view in this view:

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.demo_recyclerview).apply {

            setHasFixedSize(true)


            layoutManager = viewManager


            adapter = demoAdapter

        }
```